# Erro ao retornar valores usando $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

Eu estou tentando fazer uma página sobre dados do covid-19! Eu estou tentando pegar o número total de mortos de dois dias diferentes usando o seguinte código:

```
var ontem = $.getJSON('https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/brazil/2020' + mes.val() + '0' + diaAnt(), {"deaths": ""}).success(function(data) {
    var totais = data.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b.deaths, 0);
    return totais;
  })

var hoje = $.getJSON('https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/brazil/2020' + mes.val() + dia.val(), function(data) {
      var totais = data.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b.deaths, 0)
        
});
```

O problema é que ele sempre me retorna o seguinte dado:

```
Object { readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, … }
```

Eu já tentei de tudo mas não consigo pegar o valor exato. Alguém pode ajudar?

Edit.: O que eu quero fazer é subtrair o valor da variável "hoje" com a variável "ontem"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ontem` e `hoje` são os objetos que fazem a requisicão, os dados retornados estão disponíveis nas funções `function(data) { /* faça qualquer coisa aqui */}`

Para aguardar as duas resposta use `when`

```
var ontem = $.getJSON('https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/brazil/20200816', {"deaths": ""})
var hoje = $.getJSON('https://covid19-brazil-api.now.sh/api/report/v1/brazil/20200817');
var sub = $.when(ontem, hoje).done(
    function(dadosDeOntem, dadosDeHoje){
        debugger;
        /* faça tudo aqui */
    }
);
/* faça nada aqui */
```

Comment: Eu usei o código: var sub = $.when(ontem, hoje).done(function(totais, info){
    return totais - info;
  })
  console.log(sub); mas ainda assim ele me retorna Object { state: ƒ, always: ƒ, then: ƒ, promise: ƒ, pipe: ƒ, … }

Comment: @PedroMatiasdeSouza `var sub` não vai resover seu problema, `return totais - info` não modifica `sub`, tudo precisa ser feito dentro da função definida em `done`.